# OG_THEME module problem

Tags: organic-groups

> I configured OG_theme in drupal 7. I set a default theme for a organic
>   group and i'v got a message that is assigned to this group.

---

*My problem:*
After logging in with an OG group I see the group message and after clicking on this group message I notice the **theme changes**.

*What I want:*
After logging with a specific OG group i **directly** see the theme changes without clicking on the group message.